# Finding Alpha Numeric String from Text File

Tags: matlab

I have a `.txt` file that contains alpha numeric strings. I would like to find a specific alpha numeric string in that file and the position of every occurence.
Are there any matlab functions to do this?

Example of the string to find:
11/$$/dario

This is an example of the string that I would like to find in my text file.
The string is composed by numbers, characters and special characters like £, $, %, * and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to load in the entire file using `fread` and then use something like [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) to locate all occurrences of the specific string.

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt', 'wt');
contents = fread(fid, '*char').';

searchString = 'myString';
locations = strfind(contents, searchString);
```

Otherwise, you could use something from the MATLAB File Exchange like this [grep submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9647-grep--a-pedestrian--very-fast-grep-utility).

Comment: Is  strfind usefull to find a string with characters and number or not? for example can i find a date string like 11/12/1988?

Comment: @dario Are you looking for a specific string or a specific format? Please update your question.

Comment: i'm looking for a string with number-characers-special characters   Example: 123/$$/dario.

Comment: @dario Please update your question with an example text file and indicate which strings you want to find.

Comment: @dario In your example you'd set `searchString = '123/$$/dario'` in my code above.

Comment: ok. And what about the location= strfind(contents, searchString)? is there something to set?  is it true that the strfind function at the end give a vector with the number at witch the occurences start in my txt?

Comment: @dario yes that is true. For more information look at the help for `strfind` which I linked in my answer.